# Does signalR support multiple web servers?

Tags: signalr

I wanted to know if SignalR work in multiple web servers scenario. we have 4-5 web servers on amazon and want to use SignalR to push custom notification

Let me know, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does,

but you need to enable a backplane for it to be able to scale out. Multiple backplanes exist, among others azure servicebus and redis.

Here's an example on how to setup azure servicebus as a backplane: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently Signal R scaleout with SQL. We dont have sticky session

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using SignalR scaleout with SQL.                                              We have multiple web servers and we are not using sticky session. I'm not sure if signalR would support this scenario.

Comment: Where does SignalR, gets machine address to send it to? is it stored in database along with message? Please let us know.

Comment: I think that the message is published to all nodes, through the scaleout infrastucture, there it is kept in a buffer in memory until the user connects/reconnects to one of the nodes with a timestamp (not sure about this) and the buffer is flushed from that point on.

Comment: thanks, Yves. We are currently thinking of publishing user specific messages, messages will not be published to all subscribers. as connectionId is unique to every connection! I'm hoping we can use connectionId to channelise message to appropriate client even in the case of web farm! And somehow connectionId has information of clientIP! Thanks.

Comment: I create a signalr group per user, holding on to all the user's connections, that way i can always get back to the user, no matter what node he is connected to or what connection he's on right now. just publish to his group

Comment: Thanks, we might be sending messages to connections which are potentially not active. I was thinking to have a table and update user connection id with latest connection id!

Comment: You don't have to, that's exactly what groups are doing, keeping track of active and inactive connections and forward to the actives.